# how to set image with firebase cloud messaging?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification through Firebase cloud messaging and succeed to send push notification only for text but having issues sending notification with an image. I have tried several documentation from medium and raywenderlich but can't able to send notification with image. I have added notification extension to my project and tried this chunk of codes :

```
    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    guard let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent,
    let attachmentURLAsString = bestAttemptContent.userInfo["image"] as? String,
    let attachmentURL = URL(string: attachmentURLAsString) else{
        return
    }
    downloadImageFrom(url: attachmentURL) { (attachment) in
        if let attachment = attachment {
            bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment]
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

}

private func downloadImageFrom(url: URL, with completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationAttachment?) -> Void){
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { (downloadedUrl, response, error) in
        guard let downloadUrl = downloadedUrl else{
            completionHandler(nil)
            return
        }
        var urlPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
        let uniqueURLEnding = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString + ".jpg"
        urlPath = urlPath.appendingPathComponent(uniqueURLEnding)
        try? FileManager.default.moveItem(at: downloadUrl, to: urlPath)
        do{
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "picture", url: urlPath, options: nil)
            completionHandler(attachment)
        }catch{
            completionHandler(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

But still not showing the image, note: i am trying to send the image from firebase console. I have no idea how to find out the problem or fix it.

Comment: First thing to do is some troubleshooting; add a breakpoint and as the app receives notifications step through the code line by line inspecting the vars until you see something that isn't right. For example, perhaps the received URL is malformed; you will only know that after you've checked your code. You also have no error handling; for example in `downloadImageFrom` if downloadUrl is nil, the code will silently fail and you won't know why. You're also ignoring possible errors `downloadTask(with: url) { (downloadedUrl, response, error)` so on error, you won't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue have to be checked by adding a breakpoint and as the app receives notifications step through the code line by line inspecting the vars until you see something that isn't right.

I am sharing the code which worked perfect for me.

```
var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) { 
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)  
}

override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

And write an extension for`UNNotificationAttachment`

```
extension UNNotificationAttachment {
static func saveImageToDisk(fileIdentifier: String, data: NSData, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let folderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
    let folderURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(folderName, isDirectory: true)
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL!, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        let fileURL = folderURL?.appendingPathComponent(fileIdentifier)
        try data.write(to: fileURL!, options: [])
        let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: fileIdentifier, url: fileURL!, options: options)
        return attachment
    } catch let error {
        print("error \(error)")
    }
    
    return nil
} }
```

Comment: After adding this can i just send image using firebase console? or do i need to use postman or pusher?

Comment: You can send using firebase console itself. No need of postman.

Comment: Image Test -3, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 1621834465327725, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert =     {
        body = "bla bla";
        title = "Image Test -3";
    };
    badge = 0;
    "mutable-content" = 1;
}, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("google.c.a.udt"): 0, AnyHashable("fcm_options"): {
    image = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1589802829985-817e51171b92?ixlib=rb;
}

Comment: This is the response i am getting but not showing any image in the notification

Comment: can you please suggest me any documentation or tutorial that help me to understand this whole process?